# Кру́жево и кружа́вчик. Платье в кружавчик

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, выбор-слов, однокоренные-слова, морфемика

> Варвара Лукинишна на шейку-то бусы надела. Оленька вся в лентах. Даже Ксеня-сирота какой-то **кружавчик** из суровых ниток навертела и на темечко
> пришпилила.
> [Татьяна Толстая. Кысь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=mH8jCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT113&lpg=PT113&dq=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=zw0WEmV-gp&sig=ACfU3U3JTENKWpqPq9t8RWXcEf3IGxL2Qw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl9auTt43yAhVSiYsKHdo0D2QQ6AEwDnoECBoQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false)

В словаре Тихонова: кру́жево; корень **-кружев-**, окончание **-о**.

Возникли вопросы.

1. Какой корень в слове *кружавчик*?
   Являются ли слова *круж**е**во* и *круж**а**вчик* однокоренными?
2. Шикарное платье **в кружавчик**, комплект **в кружавчик** ― правильно ли так говорить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы  разговорного слова кружавчик - кружево/кружева, кружевце, вероятно, они однокоренные с чередованием а/е в корне. Видимо, слово "кружавчики" образовалось от основы кружев- по аналогии со словом рукав/чик. Кружева - кружавчики (уменьш.-ласкательное), кружево-кружавчик.

Шикарное платье в кружавчик, комплект в кружавчик -разговорное выражение, на мой взгляд, даже просторечное. Платье в горошек, в клетку - по всему платью горошек или клетка, а вот кружева не по всему же платью, только по краям чего-то (по полам,рукавам. карманам). Так что не совсем корректно, да и вообще, если мы хотим говорить правильно, следует избегать просторечной лексики и соблюдать морфологические и словообразовательные нормы.

Лучше сказать *Шикарное платье с кружевами*, *Комплект с кружевами*.

Comment: *даже просторечное* — или диалектное. Поиск находит слова **кружава, кружавчики** в каком-то "Среднеобском словаре" 1983 года издания.

Comment: Очень может быть, я просто не стала искать диалекты.

Comment: @grizzly Слово кружавчик (кружавчики) зафиксировано словарями (1. https://slovar.cc/rus/lopatin/1000903.html
2. www.вокабула.рф/словари/орфографический-словарь/кружавчики
3. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/337011/кружавчики) без пометок. Про кружАва ничего не знаю.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, где-то я сбился с логики, виноват.

Answer (score 1):

1. В зависимости от того, какого подхода вы придерживаетесь при морфемном разборе. Если вы считаете, что он должен происходить на синхронном (современном) уровне, то в слове *кружавчик* стоит выделить **корень *кружав-***; он будет являться алломорфом (вариантом) корня *кружев-*. Очевидно, что **эти слова однокоренные**, так как а) сохраняется единство лексического значения корня, б) выбор того или иного варианта корня обусловлен его положением в слове — *кружа́в-*, *кру́жев-*.
2. Конечно, вопрос в том, что считать правильным. Это слово, безусловно, имеет ограниченную сферу употребление, то есть не относится к общелитературным словам, поэтому если вы хотите употребить его при написании текста нейтрального стиля, **делать этого не стоит**. Используйте слово *кружево*: *платье с кружевом* или *кружевное платье*, *комплект с кружевом* или *кружевной комплект*.